# mongo db $text weight advised values

Tags: mongodb, indexing, full-text-search

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/

I am building a search index from a series of rel. fields in the database. Having done this before a while back in Solr with MySql I remember the weightings were very delicate and we had to boost fields with massive numbers to get the expected results.

In the above doc from mongo db on weights I cannot see a max value nor any guidance on what values you might want to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$text` offers the ability to [boost weights at index time](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/).
It does not offer the ability to control weightings or boost at query time.

`SOLR` is based on Apache Lucene which offers more control in terms of weights, relevance and queries.

If you are using MongoDB Atlas to host your database, you can use [MongoDB Atlas Search](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/) which is also based on Lucene and offers similar capabilities to SOLR.